# How do I enable vue.js to display images with srcset when using already compiled HTML?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive, srcset

I have a CMS that partially delivers ready-build HTML snippets via a REST interface, which get used in a VueJS application using the v-html attribute. This works fine - with the exception of images carrying the srcset attribute within this HTML. They get simply filtered out by VueJS.

Since I am not that experienced with VueJS configuration, I can't make any sense out of the Google search results that I encountered. The Vue app itself was generated using vue ui.

Comment: It is not supported by the by the html loader, they tried to add it but there where to many edge-cases so they reverted the support of srcset: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/396#issuecomment-267325098

Comment: Hi @dreijntjens - after I fixed the faulty HTML output of the CMS it worked just fine... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error was faulty HTML code generated by the CMS.